# Built data frame of two lists

Tags: python, pandas

How to build data frame out of two lists in a way shown below?
I have tried iterate over lists but I couldn't figure out way add only one element to each list.
like this:

```
for e in listone:
    for list in listtwo:
       list.insert(0, e)
```

Example:

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
```

Expected outcome:

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6],
[1 ,7, 8, 9],
[2, 4, 5, 6], 
[2, 7, 8, 9], 
[3, 4, 5, 6], 
[3, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is enough:

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]

result = [[k, *v] for k in listone for v in listtwo]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6], [1, 7, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 6], [2, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a list comprehension on `product`:

```
from itertools import product
[[x]+y for x,y in product(listone, listtwo)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 7, 8, 9],
 [2, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 7, 8, 9],
 [3, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `itertools`:

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
    
out = []
for i in listone:
    for j in listtwo:
        out.append([i, *j])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6], 
 [1, 7, 8, 9], 
 [2, 4, 5, 6], 
 [2, 7, 8, 9], 
 [3, 4, 5, 6], 
 [3, 7, 8, 9]]
```